# Stuck on even lemma with exists

Tags: coq, theorem

I'm stuck on a lemma "left as an exercise" from [this lecture](http://www.di.ens.fr/~zappa/teaching/coq/ecole11/summer/lectures/lec6.pdf). It goes like this:

```
Lemma even_double : forall n, even n -> exists k, n = 2 * k.
Proof.
  intros n H.
  induction H.
  ...
```

Where `even` is an inductive predicate defined like this:

```
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
| even0 : even 0
| evenS : forall p:nat, even p -> even (S (S p).
```

Help, please? I always end up with `(S (S p) = 2` or similar.

**EDIT**

Some lemmas and tactics I used (not complete proof):

```
destruct IHeven
exists (S x)
rewrite mult_succ_l
apply eq_S
apply plus_n_Sm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your induction step, you should have two goals.

The first one (base case for `even0`) should be easy to prove. The existential witness should be picked to be `0`, after which the goal should hold by reflexivity.

The second case (for `evenS`) would look like:

```
p : nat
H : even p
IHeven : exists k : nat, p = 2 * k
============================
 exists k : nat, S (S p) = 2 * k
```

`IHeven` says that there exists a number (let's name it `k1`) such that `p = 2 * k1`.

Your goal is to exhibit a number (say, `k2`) such that you can prove `S (S p) = 2 * k2`.

If you do the math, you should see that `(S k1)` would be the perfect candidate.

So to proceed you can use the following tactics:

- `destruct` to destruct `IHeven` to separate a witness `k1` and a proof that `p = 2 * k1`.
- `exists` to exhibit `(S k1)` as the existential witness for you goal.
- then some work to prove that the equality holds.